# My XSLT not working

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt, soap

Very new to XSLT and need help with an XSLT transformation that I can't get working.  The problem I'm having is the transformed document coming out with a blank CONO and CUNO elements.

I've been using http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_value_of.asp as a guide but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the original XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetBasicData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="CRS610MI">
<CONO xmlns="">1</CONO>
<CUNO xmlns="">123456</CUNO>
</GetBasicData>
```

Here's my XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soap:Body>
<GetBasicData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="CRS610MI">
<CONO xmlns="">
<xsl:value-of select="GetBasicData/CONO"/>
</CONO>
<CUNO xmlns="">
<xsl:value-of select="GetBasicData/CUNO"/>
</CUNO>
</GetBasicData>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the C# code I'm using for the transformation

```
    private static Boolean TransformXML(XPathDocument xPathDocument, String xslPath, out XmlDocument xmlDocument)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(streamWriter);

                    XsltSettings xsltSettings = new XsltSettings();
                    xsltSettings.EnableScript = true;

                    XslCompiledTransform xslCompiledTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
                    xslCompiledTransform.Load(xslPath, xsltSettings, null);
                    xslCompiledTransform.Transform(xPathDocument, xmlWriter);

                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);

                    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(streamReader);

                    xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception);

            xmlDocument = null;

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: "GetBasicData" and "CUNO" nodes have different *namespaces* (not namespace prefixes) - you can't possibly select it with "GetBasicData/CUNO" XPath.

Comment: What are my options?  I can't change the XML input document.  So I will need to do it in the transformation.

Comment: You need to specify correct prefixes for XPath (can't remember if there is anything special in XSLT for it or just regular prefixes are fine) or use `local-name` hack to ignore namespaces altogether. Check our [Xml Namespaces...and XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950779.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your input XML, the `GetBasicData` element has a_default namespace_ (which happens to be "CRS610MI"). On the other hand, the `CONO` and `CUNO` element do not have a namespace.

Add a namespace declaration to your stylesheet. Also, the output option `indent="yes"` makes the output more human-readable.

It appears that your intent is to put the input XML inside `soap:Body` without changing the content. In this case, you do not have to redefine everything in an XSLT stylesheet - copy as much as possible from the original XML.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:crs="CRS610MI" exclude-result-prefixes="crs">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <soap:Body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetBasicData xmlns="CRS610MI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
         <CONO xmlns="">1</CONO>
         <CUNO xmlns="">123456</CUNO>
      </GetBasicData>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: +1 looks about right. You may need prefix in XPath for `CONO`/`CUNO` too (also I think "crs:GetBasicData/CONO" is correct)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov What would you prefix them with?

Comment: You are right... They have an empty namespace - no prefix is correct. (One probably can define `xmlns:foo=""` and use it but it would look strange)

Comment: I was able to get it working with the XSLT I originally had by replacing the <xsl:value-of select="GetBasicData/CONO"/> with <xsl:value-of select="*/CONO"/>

I will try again with the new XSLT you provided.  Thanks!  Marked as answered!

Comment: Yes, that also works, @Matt. But it is not a clean solution because you're taking namespaces into consideration.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov No, namespaces cannot be empty - try it. That is, `xmlns=""` is allowed to undeclare a namespace.

Comment: Not sure what "no" relates to in your comment: `xmlns=""` specify that empty prefix maps to empty (default) namespace... (Also looks like my word usage is questionable... http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl does not define "empty namespace" concept. Maybe eventually I'll read it and figure out correct naming).

Comment: @Mathias Müller I took your advice and did it the correct way.  Had problems with the following error.  

"White space cannot be stripped from input documents that have already been loaded"  

Was able to get around it by removing "xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>" from the XSL above.